# Change color of option in select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the color of the selected option in a select element while it's in the drop down and while it's displayed in main window. So far I have been able to change the color of all the options.

```
        <select id="drop-down" onchange="colorChange(event);">
           <option value="">--</option>
           <option value="one">one</option>
           <option value="two">two</option>
           <option value="three">three</option>
           <option value="four">four</option>
        </select>
```

This is the function I'm using.

```
       var one = "one";
       var two = "two";
       var three = "three";
       var four = "four";

       function colorChange(event){
          if(event.target.value == one){
            event.target.style.color = "#67D986";
          } else if (event.target.value == two || three || four){
            event.target.style.color = "#f00";  
          } else{ 
             alert("There has been an error!!!");
       }

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in your `else if` in `OR` condition, to add conditions in `OR` use following

```
} else if (event.target.value == two || event.target.value == three || event.target.value == four) {
```

```js
var colors = {
  one: '#67D986',
  two: '#f00',
  three: '#f00',
  four: '#f00'
};

$('#drop-down').on('change', function(e) {
  var value = $('option:selected').val();
  $('option').css('color', '#000');

  if (!value) {
    alert("There has been an error!!!");
  } else {
    $('option:selected').css('color', colors[value]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop-down">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
  <option value="four">four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think I worded my question correctly. I only want the option that is chosen to change color. When you click the carrot to see all the options again they are now green/red.

Comment: is there any way to make the color appear in the main window? It's still black.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in jquery way if you like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#drop-down").on("change",function(){
      var selectedVal = $(this).val();
      switch(selectedVal)
      {
          case "one": $(this).css("color","red")
          break;
          case "two": $(this).css("color","blue");
          break;
      }
    });
});
```

Html

```
<select id="drop-down" >
       <option value="">--</option>
       <option value="one">one</option>
       <option value="two">two</option>
       <option value="three">three</option>
       <option value="four">four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i think you can achieve this even by css only here i is that check out

```css
select{
    margin:40px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
select option {
    margin:40px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

select option[val="one"]{
    background: #67D986;
}

select option[val="two"],select option[val="three"],select option[val="four"]{
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
 <select id="drop-down">
    <option val="">-----------------</option>
    <option val="one">One</option>
    <option val="two">Two</option>
    <option val="three">Three</option>
    <option val="four">Four</option>
</select>
```

**[Check By only CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/dXdq6/1162/)**